# A specific example about past tense in subordinate clause

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, sequence-of-tenses

I've read several posts about "main clause past tense, can I use simple present tense in the subordinate clause?" and I think I get the basic idea.

1. General truth can use present.

   > He didn't know that Earth moves around the Sun.
2. Indirect reported speech can use past tense. (the backshifting stuff)

   > Tom told me that Kim had blue eyes.
3. main clause past + suboridnate clause past sounds/looks more harmony.

---

What about this:

Assume that I am talking to someone:

> "Hey Tim. I had no idea that the 6th video of the tutorial **is** about English grammar. I thought it was about English vocabulary."

I want to express that:

1. I *had* no idea. Now I have.
2. The 6th video of the tutorial is so far (when I am talking) still about English grammar. But I am not sure whether the 6th video would change into something else in the future.

Should I use past tense (`the tutorial was about`) or present tense (`the tutorial is about`)?

**Which sounds native and more common?**

---

To sum up the pattern:

Main clause is past tense because it happens in the past and something described in the subordinate clause is true at the moment that I am talking about and it's very unlikey to change in the short time(days or months maybe?), but it's not a general truth.

Comment: Either is fine. So would be *Tom told me that Kim **has** blue eyes.* In fact, most people would think *had* would only makes sense if her eyes are no longer blue …  (Also, you're confusing *general* truth with *actual* or *particular* truth. All of your sentences describe things that *are* true—and demonstrably so.)

Comment: @JasonBassford What about the "English grammar" example? Does it make a difference between past tense and simple present tense used in the subordinate clause? Again, my question: Which sounds more native and common? Thanks ~

Comment: They're all fine either way—with the past or the present. I can't answer which is "more native and common."